# AJAX success function not executing

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create a simple AJAX call for testing, but have encountered a problem. I have nested in my AJAX call a success function which should pop an alert message but it doesn't. Checking firebug, the POST is successful and responds with "A20" (without quotations). Is there something wrong in my code?

**index.php (view)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="init.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="your_button">Push me</button>

</body>
</html>
```

**init.js**

```
$(function() {
$('#your_button').bind("click", function() {

var json_data = {"category": "A", "size": "20"};

$.ajax({
    url: "posted.php",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    data: {"data": json_data},
    success: function (data) {
        if (!data.error) {
            alert('k');
        } else {
            alert('error!');
        }
    }
});
});
});
```

**posted.php**

```
$category = $_POST['data']['category'];
$tsize = $_POST['data']['size'];
echo ($category);
echo ($size);
```

Comment: It would only come back as an success if it had an HTTP 200 code at it's return, check to see in the network tab, at the time of it's request to see what code it's actually returning.

Comment: And also, is that two versions of jquery you're loading?

Comment: Yes, one was not working. I deleted it but forgot to edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
$(function() {
$('#your_button').bind("click", function() {

var json_data = {"category": "A", "size": "20"};

$.ajax({
    url: "posted.php",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    data: json_data,
    success: function (data) {
        if (!data.error) {
            alert('k');
        } else {
            alert('error!');
        }
    }
});
});
});
```

Posted.php

```
  $category = $_POST['category'];
$tsize = $_POST['size'];
//echo ($category);
//echo ($tsize);
echo json_encode($_POST);
```

Your want json data but you were not echoing json data

Answer (score 1):

this is not right:

```
data: {"data": json_data}
```

do like this:

```
data: {data: json_data}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set proper headers in your PHP and send a valid json response from PHP file. Add these lines to your PHP

```
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  header('Content-type: application/json');
```

and echo back some valid json from it like echo '{"auth":"true","error":"false"}';

Answer (score 1):

First you are using two jquery libraries, remove any one of them.

Second replace `data: {"data": json_data},` with `data: json_data,`.

Third on posted.php use `$category = $_POST['category']` and `$tsize = $_POST['size'];`.

Hope it will help you.